# for what value of p does the integral converge

Tags: calculus, computational-mathematics

For what value of p does $\int_0 ^1 x^p dx$ converge?

So I used improper integral value for this, looking at the result

$$\lim_{p\to 0+} {1\over p+1}(x^{p+1}-p^{p+1})$$

*** I made a mistake, I got it now

$p\gt -1$

Comment: If $p < -1$ then the exponent of $x^{p+1}$ is negative. What happens as $x \to 0^+$?

Comment: P.S. Your formula is invalid if $p = -1$. You can handle that case separately: $\int_c^1 x^{-1}\ dx = \log(1) - \log(c) = -\log(c)$, which blows up as $c \to 0^+$.